# JavaScript compare Element.style.display

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a lot of  elements on it like below:

```
<tr class="blah" style="Display:none;">
```

When I encounter an element like the one above, I want to do some processing on it. The problem I am running into is that the "if clause" never returns a true value. The alert will display a "none" (without the quotes). I expect the "if clause" to evaluate to true. I have tried using "==" and adding a ".ToString()" after the display. This does not work.

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
    alert(rows[i].style.display);
    if (rows[i].style.display === "none") { 
        //Do some stuff 
        //Code never gets here. 
    }
}
```

Why does the comparison in the "if clause" always evaluate to false?

Comment: Works for me? See http://jsfiddle.net/Sr2J2/1/

Comment: Can you show your full HTML/any relevant CSS or a jsFiddle replicating your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly your code for me, try placing an alert inside your if clause just after it.

Just a recomendation, use **display** instead of **Display**

```
<tr class="blah" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Thanks guys. It is working now. Not sure what I had going on before.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in jsfiddle, and it works fine, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/HygdL/

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
    if (rows[i].style.display === "none") { 
        alert('okay, its works!');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that was it Alex. It is working now. Also, never seen that jsfiddle thing before. Thanks for that link!